# How to get NextJS 13 Image component to work with Tailwind?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm following the Tailwind docs, and for the following, I tried converting it to a NextJS Image component using `fill` (since it requires width and height to be specified), but doing so completely destroys the layout.

```
<div class="py-8 px-8 max-w-sm mx-auto bg-white rounded-xl shadow-lg space-y-2 sm:py-4 sm:flex sm:items-center sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-6">
  <Image class="block mx-auto h-24 rounded-full sm:mx-0 sm:shrink-0" src="/img/erin-lindford.jpg" alt="Woman's Face" fill />
  <div class="text-center space-y-2 sm:text-left">
    <div class="space-y-0.5">
      <p class="text-lg text-black font-semibold">
        Erin Lindford
      </p>
      <p class="text-slate-500 font-medium">
        Product Engineer
      </p>
    </div>
    <button class="px-4 py-1 text-sm text-purple-600 font-semibold rounded-full border border-purple-200 hover:text-white hover:bg-purple-600 hover:border-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-600 focus:ring-offset-2">Message</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How are you supposed to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the image component with the `fill` property, you will have to keep in mind that the image is of position `absolute`. meaning your container will have to be relative for the image to respect its boundaries. Here is an example:

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div className="relative h-[50px] w-[50px]">
      <Image fill src="/image.png" alt="my image" sizes="50px" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you may have seen [there is a sizes prop](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#sizes), according to the documentation this is a string that provides information about how wide the image will be at different breakpoints. The value of sizes will greatly affect performance for images using fill or which are styled to have a responsive size.